# Any cylindrical surface of dimension $2$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has zero gaussian curvature. What's the geometric intuition behind that?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces

Here I define cylindrical surface like so:

> A surface $M^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is called cylindrical if there exists a regular parametrization $x(u,v) = (a_1(u), a_2(u), \cdots,a_n(u), b(v))$ that covers all of $M^2$, where $a, b$ are real functions.

A trivial example is $X \times \mathbb{R}$, where $X$ is any regular planar curve and here $n = 2$. I know it always works out but I wanna have some intuition why.

Comment: You can create these surfaces from a flat piece of paper without any crease. This is not possible for surfaces with non-zero curvature.

Comment: @M.Winter how can one do that? It's probably obvious but I don't really see it.